# Vr hands get really big for no reason

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am useing a oculus quest with oculus link
I'm a unity vr game and I made a model for my vr hands and I heard to apply the model to your vr hands you just drag the model on to the xr Controller compment > Model Prefab. So I did that and then I tested my game. And my hands where far away from me and not linked to my controllers. Also my hands were really big to

Troubleshooting steps I took

1. I tried deleting the "Left hand" and "Right hand" In the Hiearchy and than made the left hand and right hand again and than added the xr controller compement and then dragged the hand model to the model prefab.

   2. I tried delting the model and making a new one. This did not work

Here is my unity project if you want to take a look at my problem. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XfQ1-_GGctwLSzYa2niW_6o1yJ_7IcQF?usp=sharing

I probabley did a really bad job explaing this. Sorry for any spelling errors

Comment: Do you use SteamVR or VRTK. If you dont use VRTK give it a try is much simpler.

Comment: I am using unity xr

Comment: Need to make an Empty, then put the cube in that and scale. And use the empty as the prefab.

Answer (score 0):

is the model that you're using for your hands to scale?

Unity uses 1 unit = 1 meter, and so does VR. If the models are bigger than that, they will also appear big in the VR I would make sure that the origin of your hand model (the point around which it rotates and where it will be attached to the vr controllers) is in the correct place,.